# Drawable resources | Android studio | Items

Tags: android, android-drawable, drawable

Как сделать вот такую кнопку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал вот так:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#1c1c1c"
        android:state_pressed="true">
    </item>
    <item android:color="#262626" />
</selector>
```

Но в таком случае нет красной полоски. Как её добавить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эту полоску можно создать с помощью view.

rectangle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" 
/>
<padding android:left="2dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp" />
<corners android:radius="5dp" />
<solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
</shape>
```

Добавьте этот код к кнопке:

```
<View
android:id="@+id/myRectangleView"
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>
```